# Extend <Route> element of react-router-dom to run custom logic on route match

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom

I'm using react-router v6 and I want to be able to have the following snippet in my code, and have `document.title` to be set to the value specified in `title` attribute of the `Route` element.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/groups" element={<GroupsPage />} title='Groups - Student Portal`/>
  <Route path="/classes" element={<ClassesPage />} title='Classes - Student Portal`/>
</Routes>
```

I can't seem to find a hook that would give me a currently matched route without parsing the routes myself or storing them as a javascript object.
**Question #1:** is there a way to get properties of a currently matched route?

Additionally, Routes implementation of `createRoutesFromChildren` [link](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/9fa54d643134cd75a0335581a75db8100ed42828/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L292) is not [OCP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open%E2%80%93closed_principle)-friendly. I can't think of a way to solve this without rewriting both Routes and Route with a slight modification just to allow extra properties on a route.
**Question #2:** how can I add custom properties to the `Route` element?

Comment: I'm not sure what your second question means by routes not being "OCP-friendly" means, but for the first I'd suggest creating a wrapper component that receives the `title` prop and sets the document title value. An alternative might be to create a layout route that provides a context value and each routed component updates it when they mount. I can provide examples in an answer if necessary.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying what OCP was. Do you still need help with this?